# How can I scrape bank of america for business hours?

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I was wondering how I can use beautifulsoup to scrape bank of america for its hours.
For example, if the url is
(Shattuck_Ave_94704_BERKELEY_CA/bank_branch_locations/">http://locators.bankofamerica.com/locator/locator/2129_*Shattuck*_Ave_94704_BERKELEY_CA/bank_branch_locations/)
how can i extract hours only?
Below is my initial attempt at it, but it seems to return nothing.

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
hours = soup.find_all("div", class_="lobbyHours")
print hours
```

Comment: No. But I would imagine that all branches have the same opening times wherever they are. In the UK this is true apart from some branches are closed on Saturdays. This is quite static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That url redirects, which is why `soup.find_all("div", class_="lobbyHours")` returns nothing. There is no `div` with that class on the page you're redirecting to.

By monitoring network traffic with Firefox's [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), I found that the url you are requesting actually returns a `301 Moved Permanently` status code. Fortunately, even a 301 status code, in the response headers provides a `Location` header. In this case:

```
'http://locators.bankofamerica.com/locator/locator/LocatorAction.do?shouldTest=true'
```

Which is the branch-locator page. You will have to start at this page, programmatically 'search' for the location(s) you would like, find the appropriate link, and perform a third request.

The site also uses cookies, so look into [cookielib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html).

Comment: Or use mechanize which will manage cookies and handle redirects.